# I get error when i try to $_GET for VALUES

Tags: equivalence

this is the code ia m trying to make work but apparently this is not a viable lining of code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, pass)
VALUES ('$_GET['user'], '$_GET['pword']')";
```

error i get:

```
errorError: INSERT INTO users (name, pass) VALUES ('test', '123')
Unknown column 'pass' in 'field list'
```

Comment: You need to give a few details, like where are you running this code(the platform)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have passed column on your users table in the database

I'd rewrite your codes as follows

```
$username = $_GET['user'];
$password = md5( $_GET['pword']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, pass) VALUES ($username,$password)";
```